# select a specific class with d3js to animate

Tags: javascript, class, d3.js, geometry

```
var data1 = [150,350,550]

var data2 = [100,300,500]

var sampleSVG = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 800);

var circles1 = sampleSVG
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "circles1")
    .selectAll(".circle1")
    .data(data1)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("class", "circle1")
    .on("mousedown", animateFirstStep);




var circleAttributes1 = circles1
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return d;})
    .attr("cy", 200)
    //.attr("class", function (d) { return "circle" + d;})
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d/10;})
    .style("fill", function(d){
        var color;
        if (d === 150){ color = "yellow";
        } else if (d === 350) { color = "orange";
        } else if (d === 550) { color = "red";
        } return color;
    })


function animateFirstStep(){
    d3.selectAll(...??...)
      .data(data1,function(d, i) { return d; })
      .transition()
      .delay(0)
      .duration(2000)
      .attr("r", 400)
      .style("opacity", 0)
      .each("end", animateSecondStep);
};
```

I have 3 circles and i want to click on one of them. When I click on one I want that one to grow bigger and disappear. the other 2 circles should also disappear but should NOT grow any bigger. Right now I name the class of each circle simply "circle1". But is also made a option(which are commented out) that gives each circle its own class based on the data. I have a function which animate the circles. But I don't know how to select a specific circle with a mouseclick and let that one grow bigger and disappear while the others don't grow but simply disappear. Can anyone help me out please??

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but instead of selecting elements by their class in the transition, I'd just bind the onclick event to each circle using the `.on("click", ...)` operator. You will then have access to each individual circle using the `d3.select(this)`. Here's an example of what you can do with the `circles1.on("click", ...)` function (here I'm choosing how to animate the circles by their index `i` in the original data, but you can also filter by the value of `d`):

```
.on("click", function(d, i){
    if (i == 0){
       d3.select(this).transition()
         .delay(0)
         .duration(2000)
         .attr("r", d)
         .style("opacity", 0);
    }
    else{
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
          .delay(0)
          .duration(2000)
          .style("opacity", 0);
    }
});
```

Complete working JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdml/cbgq7/).

Comment: thanks but it looks like it works only on the first circle. I want to select a circle and that that circle grows bigger and the others disappear. I also want it to remember which circle has been selected..

Comment: @michAmir: I don't think I understand what you're going for. You just want to click on a circle, have it grow bigger and disappear, and have the others fade out? What do you mean by remember which circle has been selected?

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I think this is what you want: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qrxfymvr/3/)

To "remember" the selected circle and the unselected circles, you need something like the following:

```
var grow;
var disappear;
```

Then modifying @mdml's answer a bit:

```
.on("click", function (d, i) {
    // This is an assumption, I thought you wanted to remember
    // so that you can toggle those states.
    if (grow && disappear) {
        disappear.transition()
            .delay(0)
            .duration(2000)
            .style("opacity", 1);

        grow.transition()
            .delay(0)
            .duration(2000)
            .style("opacity", 1)
            .attr("r", d / 10);

        grow = null;
        disappear = null;
    } else {
        var g = d3.selectAll("circle");
        disappear = g.filter(function (v, j, a) {
            return i !== j;
        });
        grow = g.filter(function (v, j, a) {
            return i === j;
        });

        disappear.transition()
            .delay(0)
            .duration(2000)
            .style("opacity", 0);

        grow.transition()
            .delay(0)
            .duration(2000)
            .attr("r", d)
            .style("opacity", 0);
    }
});
```

As you explained in the comments in the other answer, you wanted to select a circle and have that circle grow AND disappear. The other two circles will fade away. You also wanted to remember which was selected and which were not.

The Fiddle demo enables you to click on a circle, it will grow AND disappear, the others will fade. Click on it again and it will return to normal size, while the others will reappear.